# Adding an external JS file to Angular 5 CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have this just one Javascript function:

```
function sidemodalclose() {
    $("#sidemodal").modal('hide');
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    document.cookie = "visited=yes; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    console.log(document.cookie);
}
```

which I want to add to the home component of an Angular app.

As my `home.component.ts` has some jQuery functions which need to access the `sidemodalclose()` function.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

        $("#no-thanks").click(function() {
            sidemodalclose();
        });

        if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") == -1) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#sidemodal").modal('show');
            }, 1000)
        }

        $("#submit3").click(function() {
            $("#submit3").html("Just a sec!");
            $.post("https://thirdparty.com/api.php", $("#contact3").serialize(), function(response) {
                $("#submit3").html(response);
            });
            return false;
        });
    }

}
```

My question is what is the best way to include the small JS function in the app?

1. Is it possible to add JS functions inline in .ts?
2. If I import the JS file with `import { SideModal } from '../../assets/js/sidemodal.js';` why does it say `but '--allowJs' is not set.`?
3. What is the best practice to include custom JS functions in Angular typescript file?

Any insight is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Angular typescript file and custom js functions are not a seperated thing. You really should know what Angular is. Try `(click)` instead(https://angular.io/guide/user-input)

Comment: @HoseongSon I have tried doing that. Placing the function in `HomeComponent class` it doesn't work. Console log during execution says `sidemodalclose is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can declare your function inside your component, all your problems is solved. **You can use like any other function of your component using *this***

If you can not, so the best way is to add it to your .angular-cli.json file under the tag **scripts** so the cli load it for your before your app bundle get loaded.

And to use it in your type script you should search for **Definition Type** under @Types or write your own type file.

Once your type is available:

```
import {sidemodalclose} from 'your-type';
```